# How to prevent image src to be set continuously?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a little thing where i need to check if the `img.src` is already set or not, in order to prevent it to set continuously, as it does right now. The problem lies in my `onMove`. How can i do that?

HTML:

```
<div data-tail></div>

<button type="button" data-src="./dist/img/1.jpg">
  text 1
</button>
<button type="button" data-src="./dist/img/2.jpg">
  text 2
</button>
<button type="button" data-src="./dist/img/3.jpg">
  text 3
</button>
```

JS:

```
const tail = document.querySelector('[data-tail]') 

window.addEventListener('mouseenter', onEnter)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove)

onEnter(e) {
  let img = new Image()
  tail.appendChild(img)

  gsap.to(tail, {
    autoAlpha: 1,
    duration: 0.25
  })
}

onMove(e) {
  const el = e.target

  if (el.type == 'button') {
    const img = tail.querySelector('img')
    img.src = el.dataset.src
  }

  gsap.to(tail,{
    x:e.clientX,
    y:e.clientY
  })
}
```

Comment: Does setting `src` to the same value multiple times have some kind of visible effect, or is this a theoretical problem?

Comment: Also, this looks like a cursor – are you aware of CSS custom cursors?

Comment: I'm aware. It's not for a cursror purpose im doing it. Performance wise its not ideal i would say. Also, if i want to add a transition after src is set it will look weird since it sets continuously..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy may check if the `src` attribute is already set or not, for example:

```
if (el.type == 'button') {
    const img = tail.querySelector('img');
    img.src = img.src || el.dataset.src;
}
```

**Update:** I think you want something like this:

```
if (el.type == 'button') {
    const img = tail.querySelector('img');
    if (img.src !== el.dataset.src) {
        img.src = el.dataset.src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, no, did not do it. Sorry!

Comment: It only changes the src on enter now, not onmove.

Comment: Do you want to change the `src` `onMove`?

Comment: The code `img.src = img.src || el.dataset.src;` will set/change the `src` only there is no `src` is set.

Comment: "Do you want to change the src onMove?" Yes

Comment: Check the updated answer. @Math

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mouseover` event, which bubbles:

```
const tail = document.querySelector('[data-tail]') 

window.addEventListener('mouseenter', onEnter)
window.addEventListener('mouseover', onOver)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove)

function onEnter(e) {
  let img = new Image()
  tail.appendChild(img)

  gsap.to(tail, {
    autoAlpha: 1,
    duration: 0.25,
  })
}

function onOver(e) {
  const el = e.target

  if (el.type == 'button') {
    const img = tail.querySelector('img')
    img.src = el.dataset.src
  }
}

function onMove(e) {
  gsap.to(tail, {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY,
  })
}
```

Comment: I think this is it. Will implement it and come back!